# Controlling root access

Tags: filesystem, accessibility

I have some sensitive data and I dont want to share with the root user. As fa as I know the root users can read and modify everything. My question is how can I protect this data. I don't want to give access to the root users to this folder/file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a Linux (or any Unix) system the root user has the ultimate power to do anything.  There is no way to limit the root users ability to view, modify and execute any file or folder. This is more or less the point of the root user.

If you want to protect this folder/file the only thing I can suggest is encrypt it.
[Truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) is one option.  Just keep in mind that this will not stop the file from being moved or deleted if root so desires.

Ubuntu since 8.10 also offers to encrypt either the complete home directory of a user or a private folder. For more information see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedHome)

Comment: I would vote up, if you suggested an encrypting system different from TrueCrypt, not available in the repos, while there are many other alternatives, like encfs, ecryptfs, gpg, and similar.

Comment: Of course, root can sniff your encryption password when you enter it and then gain access to your files, so even that is a moot point.

Comment: @psusi Well that is is getting into "active" security.  There is really nothing to do about that on any operating system. Depends on how paranoid you want to be.